# Side bar height not expanding with floated content

Tags: html, css, css-float

I have a parent div with two child divs. One of the divs is a sidebar, the other, content area. I am trying to get the sidebar to extend all the way down when the content area is longer than the sidebar. Any idea how to do this ? Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SCAAa/4/) illustrating the problem.

Comment: Try: [http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=equal+height+columns](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=equal+height+columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a technique called [faux columns](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/).  The idea is that you apply a background to `#main-content`.  Since your columns are both floated you also need a clearing element at the end of `#main-content` to make it expand to the full height of both columns.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="main-content">
   <div id="side-bar"></div>
   <div id="content-right"></div>

   <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#main-content {
    background-color: #eee;
}

#content-right {
    background-color: #fff;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}
```

The above causes it to look like your `#side-bar` is the full height of the content column.

Here's [your fiddle updated.](http://jsfiddle.net/Ne8Cf/)